# Django datetime conversion

Tags: python, django, datetime, django-templates, python-datetime

In my Django program, an API call is being run to retrieve data about appointments that are taking place during the day.

In the html template, I have the following:

```
{% for session in schedule %}
    <div class="list-classes">{{ session.SessionType.Name }} with {{ session.Staff.FirstName }} at {{ session.StartDateTime }} until {{ session.EndDateTime }}</div>
{% endfor %}
```

The problem is that the output looks like this:

Cool massage 60 min with Keanu at 2021-03-09T15:20:00-08:00 until 2021-03-09T18:00:00-08:00

How can I make it look like this instead?

Cool massage 60 min with Keanu at **3:20** until **6:00**

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using the [time](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#time) filter

```
{% for session in schedule %}
    <div class="list-classes">{{ session.SessionType.Name }} with {{ session.Staff.FirstName }} at {{ session.StartDateTime|time }} until {{ session.EndDateTime|time }}</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast response. I just tried that and it does not work. It removes all the datetime parameter and displays it as follows:

Cool massage 60 min with Keanu at until

Comment: Maybe because the data from the API response is in a string format for the StartDateTime and EndDateTime, such as in the following: 
`"StartDateTime": "2021-03-10T08:00:00",
"EndDateTime": "2021-03-10T17:00:00",`